# I'm traing to modify a defined parameter in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I've defined some parameter in some bundle (Resourses/config/service.yml)

```
parameters:
    some_parameter: something
```

Then in some service inside to the same bundle I try to modify the parameter 'some_parameter' with the next

```
$this->container->setParameter( 'some_parameter', 'another thing' );
```

And when pass for this sentence give me the next error
Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag

Comment: The Symfony container is "compiled" and stored as a simple class in the cache directory.  It cannot be modified at "runtime" (hence the frozen error message).  You might be able to accomplish your goals using a compiler pass: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html

Comment: Configuration is immutable by design. You should not to modify them in runtime. Can you explain the context?